# rails new always installs new gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm just trying to figure out why when I create a new rails application, every time the initialization script is run the bundler installs new gems.  I can't find if and where it checks for new gems, anyone have any ideas.  I'm pretty sure it does check for updated gems but if someone could verify my assumption I'd feel a lot better knowing that my apps aren't going rogue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this a fair bit.  I was initially pretty alarmed but I have learned that it is because gems that you use at bundle time have been changed at the [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org) source and their dependencies on other gems changes and before you know it you are seeing lots of gems being downloaded, but mostly they are just newer versions of existing gems.

One approach to minimize this is to specify versions for every single gem but this is really not a good approach or practice long-term as you are basically freezing your application by locking everything done through gems and they will not move forward which can quickly lead to old inactive software.  However for production software which will also be moved around and where version control is tightely controlled and tested this can be very useful.  Of course versions can be done on a case-by-case (or gem-by-gem) instance for version numbers.

You can try doing two new rails app in a row (within a minute) to test that out.

Answer (score 1):

when I create a new app, I see this:

```
....
.....
run  bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using multi_json (1.0.3) 
Using activesupport (3.1.2) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.1.2) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.3.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Installing sprockets (2.1.1) 
Installing jquery-rails (1.0.18) 
.....
```

As you can see, only two gems were installed, because they have recently been updated

Comment: Indeed. Most of what it's doing is just resolving dependencies to generate a Gemfile.lock for the first time.  It won't actually install anything that's already installed, but it may resolve some newer dependencies than you already have installed.

Comment: Yeah ok so it does check for updates!  That's great, I wasn't 100% sure that's what it was doing, I wanted to be sure dependencies weren't becoming broken between development stages.  I figured thats what the source 'http://rubygems.org' on the top of the Gemfile was for